# HelloWorld facebook sample code - results different on simulator and device?

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook, facebook-wall

I am just starting to get to grips with integrating FB code into apps. I have tried the 'hello world' sample code and it works just as expected on the simulator - it posts on my wall and alongside it is the script '8 mins ago via (my app name)' All is good!!

However, if i run the app on my ipod touch, instead of the prepopulated screen coming up with the text i want to post i get a blank 'fb text input' screen, and when this is send to my wall it just has '8 mins ago via iOS' next to it...

Hard to explain clearly, and even harder for me to work out what the problem is - any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

What's happening is that the HelloFacebookSample is using the iOS6 native dialog when you run it in your iPod. This is because you've likely logged into Facebook in your iOS settings. However, in your simulator it's using a non iOS6 native dialog. The attributions in the feed story are different because an iOS6 post always says "via iOS" as this posting runs through the iOS6 flow. You'd get the same attribution if you shared a link from say Mobile Safari.